# How to create typings file in angular using old javascript code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-leaflet

I have created custom echarts layer for leaflet which is in javascript.

How to make use of that in Angular 8 using ngx-leaflet?.

Basically i want to know how to create `typings.d.ts` file so that i can use that in Angular 8.

Here is the link to my leaflet layers file in javascript.
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-tdd-xo1wm?file=/src/app/chart-layer.js

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These are a little out of date (I need to update them), but they show some examples of integrating different libraries, some of which need custom typings: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-plugins

Comment: Thanks @reblace i have tried, but i am getting error as Property 'layer' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/surajg/Development/Angular-Projects/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-ngcli/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'. Did you mean 'Layer'?

core.js:6237 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'echartsLayer' of undefined

Comment: Thanks @reblace it worked.